# Hiring coder for parts of publication

Tags: publications, computer-science, authorship, publishability

I'm designing and implementing an algorithm for 3D mesh segmentation. Probably I'll publish the results. However, I'm also interested in using this for commercial means, and to do so I need to hurry with the implementation. For that reason I'll need to hire some coders to implement parts of my algorithm.

In my publication, Do I need to reference this coders? Is this allowed in academia?

Comment: You should certainly mention how you achieved results that are not your own work.  Not sure how you "cite" a coder but I think a simple sentence like "This result was attained with the help of [Xiao Smith] and [Mohammed Jones] who were paid for their work" is plenty.

Comment: @DaveKaye: For me, this would raise the question: "Why are Smith and Jones not co-authors?"  If they made a significant intellectual contribution to the paper, they should be.  If their contributions were just mechanical, I think this should be explained.

Comment: @NateEldredge no disagreement there.  I'm not certain from the OP's question how much of a contribution is being made here...

Answer (score 2):

You would typically mention this type of help in the acknowledgements section, if at all. It is well understood that developing tooling requires manpower and that there are others on the team aside from the researchers, and it is up to the authors how to acknowledge that assistance. For what its worth, if their contribution was so significant to warrant authorship, that should be a discussion among the research team.

You mention "cite" in your question; this sort of mention would not go in your references, in case that was your thought.

Comment: *For what its worth, if their contribution was so significant to warrant authorship, that should be a discussion among the research team.* **<-- This should be done *before* you hire coders, to prevent unpleasant interactions at publication time.**